# Permutations and Combinations with inner products. : Need help!

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have two strings

String A :  $\langle e_{1}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| $

String B : $|f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{2}\rangle |f_{2}\rangle $

String B is combined with different permutations of string A. The permutations of string A are -

1. $\langle e_{1}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| $
2. $\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{1}|\langle e_{2}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| $
3. $\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{1}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| $
4. $\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| \langle e_{1}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| $
5. $\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{1}|\langle e_{2}| $
6. $\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{1}| $

String B is combined with each of the permutations from 1 to 6.

In this way for example :

$\langle e_{1}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| $   $|f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{2}\rangle |f_{2}\rangle $ = ${\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle}^4 {\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle}^1 {\langle e_{1}|f_{2}\rangle}^1$  and

$\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{1}| \langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}|\langle e_{2}| $            $|f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{1}\rangle |f_{2}\rangle |f_{2}\rangle  $$={\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle}^3 {\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle}^2 {\langle e_{1}|f_{1}\rangle}^1$

Basically, the combination happens between the end of string A and the beginning of the B string, and it goes on, outward

And you get two different kinds of strings after A and B combine -

String of type 1 :
${\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle}^3 {\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle}^2 {\langle e_{1}|f_{1}\rangle}^1$  which occurs 4 times.

And string of type 2 :
${\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle}^4 {\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle}^1 {\langle e_{1}|f_{2}\rangle}^1$   which occurs twice.

My question is this. Without going through the calculations I can say, there are two types of strings which occur.   ${\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle}^3 {\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle}^2 {\langle e_{1}|f_{1}\rangle}^1$  and  ${\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle}^4 {\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle}^1 {\langle e_{1}|f_{2}\rangle}^1$
But I cannot predict that the string of type 1 occurs 4 times and string of type 2 occurs twice. How can I predict this? How can we do this using combinatorics?

Comment: This is a little confusing. Can you tell us how you get, for example the String of type1?

Comment: @Phicar, I have added an edit to the question. Check it out :)

Comment: I would argue as this. In String A, there is a $e_1,$ so $e_1$ goes with either $f_1$ or $f_2.$ There are $4$ $f_1'$s so that is why **type 1** happens $4$ times. There are $2$ $f_2's$ so That is why **type 2** happens $2$ times.

Comment: That's just a happy accident. Suppose if string A and B were ['e1', 'e1', 'e2', 'e2', 'e2', 'e2', 'e2', 'e2'] and ['f1', 'f1', 'f1', 'f1', 'f1', 'f2', 'f2', 'f2'], you get  :                                                    {'<e2|f1>': 3, '<e2|f2>': 3, '<e1|f1>': 2}  :  occurring 10 times,
{'<e2|f1>': 4, '<e2|f2>': 2, '<e1|f1>': 1, '<e1|f2>': 1}  :  occurring 15 times,
{'<e2|f1>': 5, '<e1|f2>': 2, '<e2|f2>': 1}  :  occurring 3 times. How can you explain this?

Comment: The beauty of math is that most of stuff seems to be reducible to happy accidents :).

Comment: You should tell us what are the most general parameters of the problem. I would assume it is the numbers of $e_1,e_2, f_1,f_2$. Is it correct?

Comment: Cant we find some combinatorics such that we can predict how many strings of each type are there irrespective of the length of the string? The one in this question has 6 terms, but the example I gave now has 8. And the same reasoning doesnt work here.

Comment: @user, yes. Actually the number of e1 is given as np, number of e2 is given as n(1-p), number of f1 is given as nq and number of f2 is given as n(1-q). p and q are probabilities.  In my case, in this question n=6, p=0.2, q=0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let non-negative integers $n_{11},n_{12},n_{21},n_{22}$ be admissible counts of ${\langle e_{1}|f_{1}\rangle},{\langle e_{1}|f_{2}\rangle},{\langle e_{2}|f_{1}\rangle},{\langle e_{2}|f_{2}\rangle}$, respectively. The counts are admissible if and only if
$$
n_{11}+n_{12}=\#e_1,\;n_{21}+n_{22}=\#e_2,\;n_{11}+n_{21}=\#f_1,\;n_{12}+n_{22}=\#f_2.
$$

Then the number of sequences with the given admissible counts is:
$$
\binom{n_{11}+n_{21}}{n_{11}}\binom{n_{12}+n_{22}}{n_{22}},
$$
which corresponds to the number of ways to choose the positions of the corresponding pairs.

Comment: You are brilliant! Thank you so much. This seems to work. Could you tell me your thought process behind this solution?

Comment: This was simple. I just drew a picture (here with $n_{11}=2,n_{22}=3$): $$
e: 12122|212121\\
f: 11111|222222
$$ and asked in how many  ways the positions of $e_1$ and $e_2$ in each $f$-block can be permuted (since the result does not depend on such permutations).

Comment: Ah! I get it. Thanks!